# How to change value of variable with bash script?

Tags: c++, variables

I'm using a bash script to submit a program to run on a server, and I'm having a problem understanding how this works.
I was given a complete working script, but having trouble understanding it.

Take a look at this segment:

```
echo "Sequential,Number"

echo -n "Size"
for i in $(seq 1 1 10)
do
    for j in $(seq 500 500 10000)
    do
        echo -n "$j,"
        #Pass the image size to the program
        /home/a.out $j $j
    done
done
```

I'm trying to time how long it took to calculate an image depending on its size.  This script is running a.out with different sizes of image(pixel numbers from 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, ... to 10000, thus seq 500 500 10000), measuring the time 10 times for each image size.

What I don't understand here is how that image size from 500 to 10000 gets changed in a.out.  It says "#Pass the image size to the program" and "/home/a.out $j $j".  How does the program get this variable?  What code do I need for the a.out to receive that image size?

Answer (score 0):

`a.out` wouldn't look at `$j` -- it'd look at its command line args.

I forget how bash does it, but i'm thinking you'll want to check out `$1` and `$2`.  In C or C++ (which i assume the original program is; compilers like to name the executable `a.out` if you don't specify a name), they'll be `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`.

Comment: Thank you.. That makes sense.  It's a C++ program, do you think cin >> would work?

Comment: No.  `cin >>` would only make sense if you said something like `echo "$j $j" | /home/a.out`.  In `main`, if you've specified it like `int main(int argc, char **argv)`, in the example above `argv` will contain the arguments.  (The first one is generally the program's name, though.)

Comment: Ok. Thanks so much. This makes a lot of sense.